# Calling functions in a django app from url

Tags: python, django, function, url, dns

Consider the domain **example.content.com**. Now I want that **content.com** part to point to my django web application, and that **example** part to point to specific functions in my views.py folder, so that I can call different functions in my views.py by changing that **example** part. Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like Subdomains!

I think django-subdomains package will be best for it!

[Django Subdomain Docs](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`pip install django-subdomains`